# Nested Stream Builder not updating when trying to setstate

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-provider, stream-builder

So I am trying to get the data from assets folder in first streambuilder and in the second I am getting data from sharedpreference in the second shared preference were the list of theme is selected based on the sharedpreference position but when i try to update the data and comes to the screen from theme screen the data is getting changed and returning properly in the provider class but the snapshot.data is returning the old value for the nested streambuilder. both the streambuilder is getting called only the snapshot data is returning old data.

```
 StreamBuilder(
                  stream: _stream,
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List<String> lines = snapshot.data;
                      print('${quotesdata.themebg}');
                      quotesdata.getthemedat(context);
                      return Screenshot(
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            StreamBuilder(
                                stream: data,
                                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                    BackgroundTheme databg =
                                        snapshot.data as BackgroundTheme;
                                    print('${quotesdata.themebg}');
                                    print(databg.backgroundImageUrl);
                                    return Container(
                                      height: size.height,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          image: DecorationImage(
                                              image: NetworkImage(
                                                databg.backgroundImageUrl,
                                              ),
                                              fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                                    );
                                  } else {
                                    return Container(
                                      height: size.height,
                                    );
                                  }
                                }),
                            ScreenShotWidget(
                              homeViewModel: quotesdata,
                              list: lines,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        controller: screenshotController,
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Container();
                    }
                  }),
```

and provider methods

```
Future<BackgroundTheme?> getthemedat(BuildContext context) async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
int? theme = prefs.getInt('theme');
ThemeDataModel themelist = await locator<JsonAPI>().fetchtheme(context);
if (theme != null) {
  themebg = themelist.backgroundTheme[theme];
} else {
  themebg = themelist.backgroundTheme[0];
}
print('${themebg!.backgroundImageUrl}');
notifyListeners();
return themebg;
}

 Future<List<String>> fetchdata(BuildContext context) async {
lines.clear();

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
String? category = prefs.getString('category');
if (category != null) {
  lines = await locator<JsonAPI>().fetchquotes(category);
} else {
  lines = await locator<JsonAPI>().fetchquotes('quotes');
}
// data = lines as Future<List<String>>;
//  getthemedat(context);
notifyListeners();
return lines;
}
```

Any help or other approach will be welcome .

Comment: Are you sure you need StreamBulder and not FutureBuilder? Can't see where your stream originate, the bottom code snippet only returns Futures

Comment: Ya as the future builder will build only once  ya that future i convert into stream

Comment: If the data is not passing or updating you might have adding into stream controller to update

Comment: The code also for provider class can you post

Comment: the provider method is the only 2 method that are from the change notifier class